# Message in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I'm new to Smalltalk and i have this question.

I have written this message:

```
((Objednavkaset select:[:a | a auto porucha notEmpty])
    select: [:d | 
        (d auto porucha select:[:x | 
            x datum_poruchy
                between: x datum_vypujceni
                and: x datum_skutecneho_vraceni])
            size > 0])
```

and I have this problem, i need to access `datum_vypujceni` and `datum_skutecneho_vraceni` from this select

`select: [:d | (d auto porucha select:[:x | x datum_poruchy between: x datum_vypujceni and: x datum_skutecneho_vraceni]]`

but I don't know how, is there any way to access it?

Here is diagram if you need it.

[image: diagram]

Comment: If you would call your classes and methods in English and not in some slavic language (I don't know what it is, but I can sort of read it), more people will understand what you want to do.

Comment: Please tag your question with which Smalltalk you are using (e.g. Pharo, Squeak, VW)

Comment: So after you select/filter you want to collect/map out the variables that (the two datums)? Is that correct?

Comment: @Uko: I agree, a translation would be nice. Having programmed with non-English speakers in languages that use an "English" library and keywords, we've always found it easier to keep the code in English. I would also strongly suggest that you follow Smalltalk conventions and use `lowerCamelCase` for method names rather than `underscore_separated_naming`, and that you use _meaningful_ variable names instead of `a`, `d`, and `x`. The whole point of Smalltalk is to make it (almost) read like an English sentence that non-programmers can (almost) understand.

Answer (score 3):

As much as I like Uko's answer for the removal of the initial `select:` and the use of `anySatisfy:`, I think that Jarda's question still remains unanswered.

The actual question is how to access the two instance variables `datum_vypujceni` and `datum_skutecneho_vraceni` of `objed`, rather than how to write the selection script.

So, here is the answer to this simple question: Jarda, add two methods in your `Objednavka` class that answer these instance variables:

```
datum_vypujceni
    ^datum_vypujceni

datum_skutecneho_vraceni
    ^datum_skutecneho_vraceni
```

Once you have these methods, your script will get these data from your `objed` variable. Note also that you will need another getter to access the `datum_poruchy` of a `Poruchy`. So make sure your `Poruchy` class has the getter method

```
datum_poruchy
    ^datum_poruchy
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your goal? If you want to get all *Objednavka* that has at least one *Poruchy* that has date between other dates of the *Objednavka* it belongs to, you can do it like this:

```
(Objednavkaset select: [ :objed |
    objed auto porucha anySatisfy: [ :poruchy | 
            poruchy datum_poruchy
                between: objed datum_vypujceni
                and: objed datum_skutecneho_vraceni ] ] ]
```

also I don't know if your smalltalk has `#anySatisfy:`. If not - let me know. If you code in [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo), it definitely has

Answer (score 2):

As the innermost condition is

```
x datum_poruchy
       between: x datum_vypujceni
       and: x datum_skutecneho_vraceni
```

everything is part of the x object, so the whole condition should be there, like

```
hasValidPoruchy
    ^datum_poruchy
           between: datum_vypujceni
           and: datum_skutecneho_vraceni
```

Comment: Have you noticed that `datum_vypujceni` and `datum_skutecneho_vraceni` are not in the same class with `datum_poruchy`?

Comment: Uko, I think they are. In the question example, the innermost select block sends the three datum_ messages to x.

Answer (score 1):

In your method you use `a auto porucha` and `d auto porucha`. That long chain suggests that some behavior might not be defined on the right object. The "Law of Demeter" suggests to reduce those chains, e.g. by defining on the object this auto refers to what the `porucha anySatisfy:...` actually are

Answer (score 0):

I'll edit as you clarify what you're really after, but I can provide this much so far...

I think your first level `select:` makes it harder to see things. Using `anySatisfy:` will automatically filter out the empty ones.

```
Objednavkaset select: [:eachSet | 
    eachSet auto porucha anySatisfy:[:eachPorucha | 
        eachPorucha datum_poruchy
            between: x datum_vypujceni
            and: x datum_skutecneho_vraceni]]
```